# Can a service worker handle concurrent requests with waitUntil in the fetch handler?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am trying to implement a PWA, with a cache first strategy, which also tries to update the cache asset by fetch-ing in a waitUntil(). Will this block and make the side thread concurrent if there are multiple requests starting at (near) the same time?

Here is my code:

```
 self.addEventListener("fetch", (oEvent) => { oEvent.respondWith(
caches.match(oEvent.request).then((oRes) => {
  if (oRes) {
    oEvent.waitUntil(fetch(oEvent.request)
      .then((oFetchRes) => {
        return caches.open(DYNAMIC_CACHE).then((oCache) => {
          oCache.put(oEvent.request.url, oFetchRes);
        });
      }))
    return oRes
  } else {
    return fetch(oEvent.request)
      .then((oFetchRes) => {
        return caches.open(DYNAMIC_CACHE).then((oCache) => {
          oCache.put(oEvent.request.url, oFetchRes.clone());
          return oFetchRes;
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({}), {
          status: 503,
          statusText: "app_offline_and_missing_resource",
        });
      })
  }
})  );});
```

Any help is welcome, I am still a PWA newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More careful reading of the https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/#the_cache_machine_-_when_to_store_resources article led me to the desired answer: the stale-while-revalidate approach was what I was looking for.